# How to change language properties file programatically in ZK?

Tags: java, zk

i use in the zuls file for example:

```
<a label="${labels.menu.risinformations}" onClick="@command('loadWindow')"/>
```

and i have 3 different .properties file..hu-en-de. And my goal when user click hu a tag the zk loads from hu properties file, but when click en a tag loads from hu properties file...how can i achieve this function? Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 1):

Tested code :

```
public void changeLocale(String locale) {
    session.setAttribute(org.zkoss.web.Attributes.PREFERRED_LOCALE,
            org.zkoss.util.Locales.getLocale(locale));
    execution.sendRedirect(null);
}
```

And in the zul :

```
<menuitem label="${labels.menu.language.english}" value="en"
                onClick="ctrl.changeLocale(self.value)" checkmark="true"
                checked="${c:getCurrentLocale() == self.value || c:getCurrentLocale() == 'en_US' || c:getCurrentLocale() == 'en_GB' }" />
<menuitem label="${labels.menu.language.dutch}" value="nl"
                onClick="ctrl.changeLocale(self.value)" checkmark="true"
                checked="${c:getCurrentLocale() == self.value || c:getCurrentLocale() == 'nl' || c:getCurrentLocale() == 'nl_BE'  }" />
<menuitem label="${labels.menu.language.france}" value="fr"
                onClick="ctrl.changeLocale(self.value)" checkmark="true"
                checked="${c:getCurrentLocale() == self.value || c:getCurrentLocale() == 'fr_FR' }" />
```